# Get sum of amount monthly

Tags: mysql

I do not know English, sorry :(

**example** table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `__example__` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL, 
`fromDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
`toDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and rows:

```
INSERT INTO `__example__` (`ID`, `amount`, `fromDate`, `toDate`)
VALUES (1, 1000.00, '2016-01-16 17:05:40', '2016-01-26 17:05:45');

INSERT INTO `__example__` (`ID`, `amount`, `fromDate`, `toDate`)
VALUES (2, 1000.00, '2016-01-26 17:05:40', '2016-02-05 17:05:45');

INSERT INTO `__example__` (`ID`, `amount`, `fromDate`, `toDate`)
VALUES (3, 1000.00, '2015-12-26 17:05:40', '2016-01-05 17:05:45');

INSERT INTO `__example__` (`ID`, `amount`, `fromDate`, `toDate`)
VALUES (4, 4000.00, '2015-12-26 17:05:40', '2016-02-04 17:05:45');
```

I want to see:

```
year | month | sum
2015 |    12 | 1400.00
2016 |    01 | 4700.00
2016 |    02 | 900.00
```

Example:

2 rows started at 12/2015 and the sum thereof is 5000.00(1000+4000).

But 12/2015 sum column should be 1400.00.

How can I do that with SQL query? Help me, please.

Comment: Please provide the arithmetic that explains how to compute the 900.

Answer (score -1):

This query should accomplish your goal.

```
Select YEAR(fromDate) [Year], MONTH(fromDate) [Month], SUM(amount) [Amount]
FROM '__example__'
GROUP BY YEAR(fromDate), MONTH(fromDate)
ORDER BY Year, Month
```

Comment: Hi Squatch307. Thanks for your answer. But, I do not want to sum by fromDate or toDate. I want to sum of that dates between in month start and month end date between.

Comment: If I'm now understanding your requirements better, the data being inserted can't be extrapolated into the table you're wishing to produce. Your insert values cross multiple months and/or years. The table values aren't specific enough to tabulate when in the period inserted the value was produced. For example, the fourth insert has a from date covering a period of 2015/12/26 - 2016/02/04. How is the query to determine whether that amount value of 4000 should be applied to 2015/12, 2016/01 or 2016/02?

Comment: I read the edit you added to the original post. Based on the information in the table, extrapolating a value of 1400 for 12/2015 is not possible.

Answer (score -2):

I've still never used mysql.  But Looking at your edited requirements, I THINK you're asking for something like this:

1. Take the total amount and divide it by the number of days between
   todate and fromdate.
2. Find the number of days in the month from the "fromdate" to the end
   of the month.
3. Multiply the average amount (step 1) by the number of days in each
   month to get the value in each month.

If that's what you're asking for then the solution is pretty easy.

You'll first need a row for each month in the span.  I'd suggest creating a "DATES" table and joining Examples to the date table.  Create a row in the table for every month between 2015 and 2020 (like '01/01/2015', '02/01/2015', '03/01/2015', etc.).

After this, and using the mysql LAST_DAY() and DATE_ADD functions, you should be able to calculate the average amount per day (=amount/total days).

Comment: Hi paulbarbin. Thanks for your answer. But, I do not want to sum by fromDate or toDate. I want to sum of that dates between in month start and month end date between.